# Sending a JSON request to launch a Google Apps Script

Tags: json, google-apps-script, get

I am trying to create a new Google Doc using Apps Script. 
Here's the code of my macros:

```
function createDoc() {

      var doc = DocumentApp.create('Sample Document');
      var body = doc.getBody();
      var rowsData = [['Plants', 'Animals']];
      body.insertParagraph(0, doc.getName())
          .setHeading(DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.HEADING1);
      table = body.appendTable(rowsData);
      table.getRow(0).editAsText().setBold(true);
    }
```

I have also generated a link for this script as a web app (it looks like this: https://script.google.com/macros/s/[SCRIPTID]/exec). Now I have to send GET request but I don't know what JSON command should I send. Could you please help?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: In order for an Apps Script function to be triggered from an external GET request, you must have a function with the reserved function name `doGet()`  There are two reserved function names that monitor for GET and POST requests made to the published URL: `doGet()` and `doPost()`.  You want to use a GET request, so you need to have a `doGet()` function.  How that GET request gets made to your Apps Script URL depends upon the programming language that you will be using to make the GET request.  If you need to make a GET request *from* Apps Script, use `UrlFetchApp.fetch(url)`

Comment: Hello Sandy! Thank you for your help! I've added function ` doGet(request) {
  createDoc();
} ` there and tried to invoke but Google returns with **Script function not found: doGet**. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Could you update the code in the question to reflect the changes you made? Also, do you want new document created each time you access/request the web app?

Comment: Did you update the scripts web link by changing the project version to new? If you just say update, it doesn't update to the latest code!

Comment: Well, what I did is I created a new script and copied the functions there. Repeated the process — and it worked!

Comment: Is there a quicker way to update, without creating a new script file and re-linking its token?

Comment: If you need help with general advice, it's better to ask the question in a different forum or group.  There is an Apps Script group in a GPlus community:  [Link to Apps Script Community](https://plus.google.com/communities/102471985047225101769)  It's better not to have extended discussions in the comments section.  If you have another issue that would be a good question, post another question.

Comment: Alright, it makes sense. Thanks everyone for your responses!